# $smarty.get.page не передаёт данные в php

Tags: php, smarty

У меня есть input где я в value указал вот так >

```
value="{$smarty.get.page}"  name="page"
```

Чтобы брать utm метку

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=foo
```

В php пишу вот так чтобы взять данные с инпута

```
$utm = $_GET['page'];
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я ввёл всё как по документации 
**https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.variables.smarty.tpl**
Чтобы в input value поместить метку 'page'
и взять её из php. Но приходит пустая метка.(Или вообще не приходит)

Comment: @ArcWarden я проверил ваш вариант, он возвращает то, что требуется. `<form action="test.php" method="GET">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="{$smarty.get.page}"  name="page">Предоставить данные</button>
            </form>`, по крайней мере, через form работает, если в url есть page=foo. Вам бы в вопросе больше кода указать...

Comment: У меня Метод post, значит мне надо изменить на $utm = $_POST['page']?

Comment: @ArcWarden я подумал, что фигню написал про form, вам бы написать в вопросе больше кода php и tpl...

Comment: Я могу скинуть в codepen > https://codepen.io/IgorPlays/pen/ExmMdQM?editors=1012

Comment: @ArcWarden да, не знаю, чем вы занимаетесь, но вот ваш код, если его смотреть через F12.
`<!----> Вот тег который берёт интуп  <!---->
              <input type="hidden" name="page" class="page" value="foo">`
При адресе http://localhost/int/test.php?page=foo

Comment: https://ibb.co/6JbVFg4

Comment: @ArcWarden https://ibb.co/vVdFwPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы уже не первый вопрос задаете на одну и ту же тему, не особо понимая, что и как работает, поэтому давайте разбираться в том как вещи устроены.

Клиент с сервером общается с помощью http-запросов. Запросы могут быть разных типов. В основном используются два основных `get` и `post`. Первый предназначен для получения данных, второй для изменения.

Когда вы пишите ссылку в адресной строке или совершаете переход через `<a>` браузер отправляет `GET` запрос. Для отправки `POST`-запроса используются формы `<form method="POST">`.

Параметры url, которые указаны после `?` (`?param=1&param2=2`) на стороне пхп попадают в массив `$_GET`. Параметры формы с соответствующим методом - в массив `$_POST`. Все вместе доступно в массиве `$_REQUEST`.
Если `action` формы выглядит как `xxx.php?param=1`, а сама форма содержит некие поля, то у вас будет заполнены оба массива. в `$_GET` получите `['param' => 1]` а в `$_POST` все остальные поля формы. То есть формально массивы привязаны не к типу запроса, а в `$_GET` мы получаем параметры из url (вне зависимости от типа запроса), а в `$_POST` данные формы при post-запросе.

Далее. Smarty это шаблонизатор. основная его задача - преобразовать `.tpl` шаблон в исполняемый пхп код. Все конструкции вида `{foreach}, {if}` и т.п. компилируются в обычные пхп файлы, которые доступны в папке `compile`. При разработке имеет смысл настроить перекомпилцию шаблона при его изменении. при этом каждый раз смарти проверяет дату изменения файла и дату компиляции шаблона, если надо -  обновляет. В продакшен среде такие проверки отключают. скомпилированные шаблоны удаляют при необходимости их обновить.

Для доступа к переменным запроса смарти имеет зарезервированные переменные `get/post`. Например, для формы вида

```
<form action="?param=1" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="field" value="2"/>
```

значения переменных можно получить через  `{$smarty.get.param}` или `{$smarty.post.field}`, также есть `{$smarty.request.}` где доступны оба значения.

Для вывода данных, полученных от пользователя, используют экранирование с помощью модификатора `escape`. Пример - `{$smarty.get.param|escape}`, в противном случае можно получить инъекцию js либо  html.

На практике прямое использование `smarty.get/post` не шибко то распространено. Шаблоны по сути предназначены для вывода/представления данных. А параметры в основном предназначаются для обработки в бизнес-логике. Так что обычная схема работы выглядит следующим образом. В пхп коде вы получаете нужные данные запроса, передаете их в смарти с помощью метода `assign`, а там уже используете.
Пример:

```
 <?php

 $page = intval($_GET['page']) ?? 0;

 $smarty = new Smarty();
 $smarty->assign('page', $page);
 $smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

и шаблона

```
<a href="?page={$page+1}">далее</a>
```

Если по какой-то причине у вас есть url вида `?page=1`, но при этом `{$smarty.get.page}` дает пустой результат, значит где-то  в процессе работы пхп кода массив `$_GET` либо `$_GET['page']` были очищены. Повторюсь, что ключевым способом работы является явная передача нужных данных в шаблон через `assign`, либо другие способы в случае использования различных фреймворков, а не прямого использования smarty.